# How to get week numbers for given two dates in different year - php / mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Actually I need to get the week numbers with total quantity. please check the below query.

```
SELECT WEEK(oi.lastupdated) AS week_number, SUM(oi.quantity) as 'total' FROM orders_item oi
JOIN orders ord on ord.orderid=oi.orders_orderid
JOIN product prod on prod.sku=oi.sku
WHERE oi.sku= 'ZFAFBK'
AND ord.status = 4
AND oi.lastupdated >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY week_number
ORDER BY week_number DESC
```

The above query will return the number of weeks for the year. but its resetting the week number for the different year.

Example if i want to find week number `2017-02-19` to `2018-02-19`, then the week numbers start from 1 for the `2018`. But I want `0 - 52` weeks even though different years.

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: could you please add your table scema with some data?

Comment: Pass the dates to client. And write lines of code to get your week numbers. Because it includes more calculations